# Extending IQueryable to return objects where a property contains a string

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0, iqueryable

I see a lot of code similar to the following

```
var customrs = MyDataContext.Customers.Where(...);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) {
  customers = customers.Where(c => c.Email.Contains(input));
}
```

I would like to put this in an extension method that checks the input is valid before invoking Where on IQueryable so that it can be called like

```
customers = MyDataContext.Customers.Where(...)
  .ContainsText(c => c.Email, input);
```

My extension method looks like this

```
public static IQueryable<T> ContainsText<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, string>> selector, string text) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) {
    return source;
  }
  else {
    //do something here
  }
}
```

How can I call Contains() on the expression parsed? Or is there another way to return IQueryable of results where the expression parsed contains the text parsed?

**Update**: It's for Linq to Sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[tvanfosson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688020/extending-iqueryable-to-return-objects-where-a-property-contains-a-string/1688183#1688183) had the right idea with building the expression which led to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278684/how-do-i-create-an-expression-tree-to-represent-string-containsterm-in-c/278702#278702) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278684/how-do-i-create-an-expression-tree-to-represent-string-containsterm-in-c). So for completeness here is a full working solution

The expression builder

```
public static class ExpressionBuilder {

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ContainsText<T>(string propertyName, string text) {
    var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
    var propExp = Expression.Property(paramExp, propertyName);
    var methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var valueExp = Expression.Constant(text, typeof(string));
    var methCall = Expression.Call(propExp, methodInfo, valueExp);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(methCall, paramExp);
  }

}
```

The extension method

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions {

  public static IQueryable<T> ContainsText<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, string>> selector, string text) {
    if (source == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    if (text.IsNullOrEmpty()) {
      return source;
    }
    string propName = ((MemberExpression)selector.Body).Member.Name;
    return source.Where(ExpressionBuilder.ContainsText<T>(propName, text));
  }

}
```

Invoked like

```
var customers = MyDataContext.Customers.Where(/* some code */)
  .ContainsText(c => c.Email, input);
```

Comment: Hey, I've a question regarding this piece of code. It looks like something I can use, one thing though: the expressions are translated to a SQL query with AND statements in it when I chain them: ... WHERE thing LIKE ... AND thing2 LIKE ... 

Do you know of some way to change this behavior to OR? Is this done in some setting? or should I write alot of code that somehow uses Expression.Or?

Answer (score 3):

I think I would make the extension on String, not on IQueryable.

```
public static bool ContainsIfNotEmpty( this string source, string text )
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
       return true; // select all elements
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    {
       return false; // select no elements
    }
    return source.Contains(text); // select only matching
}
```

Then use it as:

```
customers = MyDataContext.Customers
                         .Where( c => c.Email.ContainsIfNotEmpty( input ) );
```

Note that this requires LINQ to objects.  If you need to use it with LINQ to SQL, then I'd suggest building the expression using a builder method.  Note the following is untested as I don't have access to VS right now.  You might want to look at Andrew Peters' [blog entry](http://andrewpeters.net/2007/04/24/dynamic-linq-queries-contains-operator/) for a similar example and/or the documentation on the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) class.

```
public static class ExpressionBuilders
{
    public static Expression<Func<T,bool>> ContainsBuilder<T>( string column, string text )
    {
          ParameterExpression parameter = new Expression.Parameter( typeof(T), "t" );

          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
          {
              return (Expression<Func<T,bool>>)QueryExpression.Lambda( Expression.Constant( true ), parameter );
          }

          MethodInfo contains = typeof(T).GetMethod("Contains");
          Expression textExpression = Expression.Constant(text);
          Expression containsExpression = Expression.Call(parameter,contains,textExpression);

          return (Expression(Func<T,bool>))QueryExpression.Lambda( containsExpression, parameter );
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
var predicate = ExpressionBuilders.ContainsBuilder<Customer>( "Email", input );

customers = MyDataContext.Customers.Where( predicate );
```

Comment: I'm looking for Contains(input) not Equals(input), is that possible using dynamic Linq?  It's for Linq to Sql.

Comment: Sorry -- I missed that.  It gets more complicated and you can't use Dynamic LINQ, but have to build the expression yourself.  I've included some (untested) code that may work or at least give you a hint as to how it could be done.

Comment: Thanks, this led me to a solution. There are a couple of syntax errors in your expression builder and I don't have the rep to edit them so I've posted a full working solution for anyone to see.

Answer (score 1):

The following would be possible using `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ContainsText<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, string> selector, string text)
{
  return source.Where(
      x => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selector(x)) &&
           (selector(x).Contains(text))));
}
```

In order to stay in the `IQueryable<T>` your only options would either be Dynamic Linq as tvanfosson has suggested or [User Defined Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399416.aspx).

But to be honest, you might aswell just stay with `Where`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this instead:

```
customers = MyDataContext.Customers.Where(c =>  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || c.Email.Contains(input)));
```