# Like operator and dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using dynamic linq and was trying to implement contains logic...I need to return

```
Func<Expression, Expression, bool, MethodInfo, BinaryExpression>
```

sample code for equal

```
private static Func<Expression, Expression, bool, MethodInfo, BinaryExpression> GetFuncForOperand(OperatorType operand)
        {
      case OperatorType.Equal:
                    func = Expression.Equal;
                    break;
                case OperatorType.NotEqual:
                    func = Expression.NotEqual;
                    break;
case Operatortype.Like
//         what should I do
}
```

how can I express contains ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your existing code. Even the code you have doesn't remotely compile. That said, Contains logic would be implemented via a MethodCallExpression, not a BinaryExpression.

Comment: as Jeff pointed out you need a `MethodCallExpression` and an array to perform the `Contains` operation on, have a look at this SO thread for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278684/how-do-i-create-an-expression-tree-to-represent-string-containsterm-in-c

Comment: I am still trying to wrap my head around expression concept. if some one can quickly code this would be great... I have to deliver something soon...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my [blog post](http://blog.alivate.com.au/?p=382), I made my own Like evaluator in c#, complete with unit test.