# How to search with dynamic entity names with linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, search

Basically all I'm looking to do is something like the following:

```
string EntityFrameworkType = "Product";
string searchField = "ProductName";
string searchValue = "My Product";

using( var context = new entitycontext())

{
var result = (from x in context.EntityFrameworkType.Where(l=>l.searchField == searchValue) select x).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

of course this syntax won't work because context does not contain an entity called "EntityFrameworkType"...

Is it possible to do this another way??? What I'm looking to do in generalize my database duplicate check. In this example, I'm searching for any Product with the Name "My Product". But I'd like to be able to pass in these string for say, ProductCategory with ProductCategoryId = 1.... etc...

Comment: So instead of type-safe compile-time checked statements, you want to use a bunch of strings and munge them together at runtime. Remind me again why you are using LINQ and not just using dynamic SQL (shudder). Perhaps you should instead look into T4 templates to generate some code for you.

Comment: Thought about t4... not really wanting to take that route. The reason for this is to have a single method to check whatever entity type and whatever entity type field against whatever value for dups. I could of course just write a method for each entity type but... hoping to just have the one method capable of handling whatever. I guess this is also because of relationships with the types. If I want to create a new Product which has a many to many relationship with ProductCategory, I don't want to duplicate the product OR any of the ProductCategories... it gets messier and messier as I go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278684/how-do-i-create-an-expression-tree-to-represent-string-containsterm-in-c) to get the idea of how it is done.

You'll need to learn about `Expression`

Comment: This is what I was looking for... Thanks for the point in the right direction