# Method to add Linq expressions to a list of expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I have a list of Linq expressions like:

`List<Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>>`

I need to add a whole bunch of predicates from a search page, like:

```
x.Name.Contains(searchString)
x.Description.Contains(searchString)
...
```

I want to create a method so I don't end up with a mass of duplicated code. Something with a signature like:

```
void AddCustomerPredicate(List<Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>> predicates, Expression<Func<Customer, string>> prop, string searchString);
```

Which I would use like:

```
var predicates = new List<Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>>();
AddCustomerPredicate(predicates, x => x.Name, this.Name);
AddCustomerPredicate(predicates, x => x.Description, this.Description);
...
```

I've simplified the problem a bit, but that is the gist of it. I haven't done much work with expression trees and the like, so I'm not sure how to implement this method?

**EDIT**

I might have over simplified the problem too much. I know how to add to the list like `predicates.Add(x => x.Name.Contains(this.searchString))`, but I have various things I want to do on each search parameter before adding it to the list (e.g. check for null or empty). I therefore want to call a method on each search parameter as above, so all of that stuff can be contained in a single method.

Comment: Do you want to evaluate all the predicates on each result?  And if so, do you want to "AND" them together, or "OR" them?

Comment: I want to AND them together. I've no problem with that part tho, it's dynamically adding to the list using a method I can't figure out

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that nature of your difficulty.  You would add the expressions to the list just as you would add anything to a list, e.g., the same way you would add a string to a list of strings.  Is there a deeper requirement you have left out?  Are you trying to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Never mind, I think I see what you are asking.  You want to transform the accessor expression into a predicate that checks against the provided value, yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really need is to have a method for translated `Expression<Func<T, string>>` to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` :

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetContainsExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> prop, string searchString)
{
    var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var someValue = Expression.Constant(searchString, typeof(string));
    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(prop.Body, method, someValue);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, prop.Parameters[0]);
}
```

This is inspired by this other answer : [How do I create an expression tree to represent 'String.Contains(“term”)' in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278684/how-do-i-create-an-expression-tree-to-represent-string-containsterm-in-c)

```
var predicates = new List<Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>>();
predicates.Add(GetContainsExpression((Customer x) => x.Name, this.Name));
predicates.Add(GetContainsExpression((Customer x) => x.Description, this.Description));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will do what you want, and will also handle `null` property values (so calling `Contains()` does not throw):

```
private static void AddCustomerPredicate(
    List<Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>> predicates,
    Expression<Func<Customer, string>> accessor,
    string searchString)
{
    var x = accessor.Parameters[0];
    var temp = Expression.Variable(typeof(string), "temp");

    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(
        Expression.Block(
            new[] { temp },
            Expression.Assign(
                temp,
                accessor.Body),
            Expression.AndAlso(
                Expression.IsFalse(
                    Expression.ReferenceEqual(
                        temp,
                        Expression.Default(typeof(string)))),
                Expression.Call(
                    temp,
                    "Contains",
                    Type.EmptyTypes,
                    Expression.Constant(searchString)))),
        x);

    predicates.Add(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Does this work if the user want a non memberexpression like `AddCustomerPredicate(predicates, x => x.Age.ToString(), "18")`?

Comment: This throws if I try to use a nested property like `x => x.Company.Name`.

Comment: Expression.Invoke won't be able to be properly understood by most query providers, they'll just fail at runtime.

Comment: For that matter, they probably won't handle block expressions either :-/.

Comment: @MikeStrobel they don't, I had a problem with that too ;)

Comment: Yeah, if you're using these expressions with a query provider, then you essentially have to slim my answer down until it's equivalent to @CyrilGandon's.